# setState is not updating or re rendering DOM or component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, jsx

I cant figure out why my Login component is not re-rendering what is on the page. The state is changed to loginShow after I click on a "Log In" button on top of my form.

```js
    import React from 'react';
    import SignUp from '../SignUp';
    import Cards from '../Articles/Cards';
    import Login from '../LogIn';


    export default class Gecko extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = { requestedPostsThatWeGotFromGecko: null,  }
            this.clickMe = this.clickMe.bind(this)

            this.state = {
                loginStatus: "loginHide",
                authType: "signup"
              };
            
              this.loginClose = this.loginClose.bind(this);
              this.loginOpen = this.loginOpen.bind(this);
      }

      loginClose(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        this.setState({
          loginStatus: "loginHide"
        });
      }
      
      loginOpen() {
        this.setState({
          loginStatus: "loginShow"
        });
      }
        
        clickMe = () => {
            const {requestedPostsThatWeGotFromGecko} = this.state;
            this.setState({ requestedPostsThatWeGotFromGecko: !requestedPostsThatWeGotFromGecko })
        }
    /*  mainLogIn = () => {
            const {loginStatus} = this.state;
            this.setState({ loginStatus: 'loginHide' })
        } */
        render() {
            const { requestedPostsThatWeGotFromGecko } = this.state;
            const { loginStatus } = this.state;
            console.log(loginStatus);
    //      const { authType } = this.state;
    //      if (loginStatus === "loginHide") return <SignUp login={() => this.clickMe()} /> 
    //      if (requestedPostsThatWeGotFromGecko.props === true) return <Cards />
            if (loginStatus !== "loginShow") return (
                <div className="gecko">
                 {requestedPostsThatWeGotFromGecko ? (
                   <Cards />
                 ): (
                  <SignUp login={() => this.clickMe()} />
                 )
                 }
               </div> 
             );
             if (loginStatus === "loginShow") return <Login /> 
              
          }
    }
```

I believe the issue lies where I am trying to set what is being displayed using the conditional operator at the end of the code above. I have included where I am setting the state and props from my other components in the code below.

```
const onClick = () => {
        this.props.login();
        console.log('rich');
    }
    const mainLogIn = () => {
        this.setState({
            loginStatus: "loginShow"
          });
        console.log('rich1');
        console.log(this.state);
    }

const onClick = () => {
        this.props.login();
        console.log('rich');
    }
    const mainSignUp = () => {
    this.props.signup();
        this.setState({
            loginStatus: "loginHide"
          });
        console.log('rich2');
    }
```

Comment: One thing to note, is that in your constructor, you should only be doing ```this.state = {}``` one time. You do ```this.state = ``` twice and the second one will overwrite the first one. So your initial state is equal to ```{ loginStatus: "loginHide",authType: "signup"}```

Comment: @Chris thanks for pointing that out. I have removed it but unfortunately that wasn't the root of the problem

Comment: It seems like there is code missing that makes it difficult to find the underlying problem. Can you provide the code for the component where you are making the method calls and expecting state to change?

Comment: @Chris They are listed in the original post at the bottom. Those a functions that fire when a button is pressed with an onclick event. the top two are from one component page and the bottom two are from another.

Comment: It would help if you had only the relative information. It seems like the mainLogIn is being called from your LogIn component, and is expected to be setting state of the Gecko component, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: @Chris what would be the easiest way of showing you what you need without clogging up this thread with a bunch of files and code blocks?

Comment: Codesandbox is great for larger examples so I can pick at your code a bit easier and see what's wrong. They have a React template you can use.

Comment: @Chris I didn't create one due to time constraints but here is my git repo https://github.com/guycode/gecko-repo

Comment: Looking at the repo, there is quite a bit that needs to get stripped/changed within the app. It's hard to pin point exactly what is going on and what is supposed to do what. I managed to get your log in button working so you can switch to the login view by clicking on the login button. You'll want to play close attention to where you are using props methods and where you are using setState. I see you're trying to setState in your SignUp component to switch to loginShow, but it's the Gecko component that actually holds the state.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220181/discussion-between-guycode-and-chris).